# How can I send STX and ETX over serial port in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, serial-port, hex

I'm trying to receive a chain from a serial port, and writing it to another serial port
easy right?
receiving the data is no problem, but when i try to write exactly the same byte array to the other port, STX and ETX dissapear, and I really can't figure  why.
the chain format is:

```
<STX><VALUE><ETX><LRC>
```

when converting  the byte array to string, the 02 and 03, values of STX and ETX still there, but when i send the byte array to the other port, it only sends `<VALUE><LRC>`

Example:

received chain byte array, converted to string.

```
026131300360
```

ascii representation

```
.a10.`
```

ascii received in the second port

```
a10`
```

My code

```
Queue<Byte[]> Port1Tail= Port1.lista; // a queue of byte arrays received

if (volumTail.Count > 0)
            {
                Byte[] cadena = Port1Tail.Dequeue(); 
                StringBuilder tramabuild = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (Byte b in cadena)
                {
                    tramabuild.Append(((Int16)b).ToString("x"));
                }
                String trama = tramabuild.ToString();  
                Byte[] cale = ToByteArray(trama);

                inputlistbox.Items.Insert(0, trama); 


                Port2.Send(cale, 0, cale.Length);
                //Port2.Send(cadena, 0, cadena.Length);

            }
```

As you could notice, I already try to send the received chain exactly as i received it, and even try to convert it to string, and then back to byte array with the exactly same result.

Can somebody please tell me  what im doing wrong?

Comment: And why are you doing all this? If you just want to send the array... then just send the array. Don't convert it back and forth a few times.

Comment: Already try it, //Port2.Send(cadena, 0, cadena.Length); whith same result, STX and ETX dissapear

Comment: What types are Port1 and Port2? The `SerialPort` class does not seem to have a method `Send`. Did you write that?